# Iterate through one table to update another table on sql

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, count

I'm using Postgresql and it is costly to use count. What I'm trying to do is counting one table ids in another one and update count number. 
Let's say first table is categories

id

name

num_count

Other table is Restaurants

id

name

category_id

I want to update categories.num_count based on the count value of Restaurants.category_id. 
I can do this with 
`Update Categories set Categories.num_count = (select count(*) from Restaurants where Restaurants.category_id = Categories.id)`
yet it tooks too much time. I tried to do something like iterate Restaurants 1 time and update Categories.num_count ++ but i couldn't do it right because it makes every categories num_count 1. It stops working after 1 execution.

Is there a better way to do this with sql?

Comment: The better way is to not do it - use a view instead, or calculate the count as and when you need it. The problem with your approach of storing *derived* data is maintaining it.

Comment: You are right but it is already a snapshot of a database and there will be no adding or removing. Still i can try to use view. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update categories c
set num_count = r.num_count
from (
    select category_id, count(*) as num_count
    from restaurants
    group by category_id
) r
where c.id = r.category_id
```

Comment: I couldn't understand why it is worked so fast because there is still count in this sql. is it because group by?

Comment: @mbaydar It does all counts at once

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
with countPerCategory (categoryId, numCount) as
{
  select category_id, count(*) from Restaurants
  group by category_id
}
update Categories set num_count = countPerCategory.numCount
from countPerCategory
where Categories.id = countPerCategory.categoryId;
```

PS: I find it an unnecessary thing to do. You need to update the num_count whenever a Restaurant is added or deleted.

Comment: You are right but it is already a snapshot of a database and there will be no adding or removing.